# Hide specific columns in Cognos 10

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have created a crosstab in Cognos 10 & I have specified the logic for each row.
I also have specified the logic for the column but I have a problem.
As shown in the attached picture, when I run the report, the column is showed 2 times.

The column logic is:

CASE 
WHEN ([FBA].[FEFRecord].[BL] ='SPEC') THEN ('Special Customers')
ELSE NULL
END

I guess that the problem is that all the values which are not in 'SPEC' are allocated in a new column (which holds the null values).

Can you please show me step by step what should I do to display the column only once, without the NULL values?
I also tried adding a Boolean variable and setting the BOX TYPE to NONE, but it seems like it is not working for me.

Note: As shown in the picture, I only need the second column, not the one with the red X.[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be just filter them out completely?
Add a filter

```
[FBA].[FEFRecord].[BL] ='SPEC'
```

But it looks like you problem isn't here.
In case you see null column header wouldn't be 'Special Customers'.

My guess you have another node here.
Switch to Page Structure View and check it.